# Understanding scenes in blender. (linked objects)

Tags: linked-data, scene

I have a problem understanding the scene setup in Blender 2.8.

I created a scene with animations (keyframes, follow path contstraints, nla tracks, etc).

Now I wanted to create a new scene, in which I want to reuse my main character.

But when I link it into the new scene, it comes with all the animations of the previous scene. 
I tried already several Objects->Relations settings, but with no success.

I saw a tutorial (for an older version) with Link Object Data, which did the trick - if I understood the video correctly. 
But unfortunately, this option is missing in 2.8

Is there a proper way to link only the object without its animations, so I can start the scene from scratch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The way linked option is intended is to have a base file in which you perform modeling, rigging, skinning, texturing and everything referred to the "building" of characters, props, environments and so on.

Then instances of all theese objects can be linked into a new file in which you will perfom the scenes, animations, lighting, camera movements and so.

The idea is that if you decide later to modify something in one character, the edit will be reflected into all the scenes in which that character has been used.

So, for a "correct" workflow you can simply save a new version of your file, delete all the animations, and link from this new file.

I've read that the link function will be changed in future, to let edits also over linked objects (by now you can also use the simpler "append" function, which will not automatically reflect any new change in the base file).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I modified my setup accordingly. Unfortunately I am facing major issues with it. For example, I changed the pivot poit (origin) for armature and mesh of the original object.

As a result the Mesh and armature of the linked objrct in my scene gets disconnected. I tried already to make a new proxy and other things without success.

The original and the linked one, if no proxy is added, are fine, but once I add a proxy. I get the issue.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a good tutorial for linking available?

Answer (score 0):

If you duplicate the project and go into the duplicated one, then delete all objects in the scene other then the character and export it as whatever format you want (obj preferred). Then just import that obj back into the original project and it should have no animations.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
I linked the individual objects. 
Now I added all to a collection and linked that. That did the trick. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem had me stumped the whole evening, but I found a working solution. (in Blender 2.93.5)

I'm not sure about animations as I only tested with a static scene.

For me it works like this:

- Create the object
- Create a new scene
- In the original scene select: Object -> Link/transfer Data -> Link object to scene -> and select the second scene

[image: Link objects to other scene]

- Now in the second scene select the object(s)
- Select: Object -> Relations -> Make Single User -> Object
- Now you can change the position (and location and scale) in the second scene without it moving in the first scene. But still retain the linked geometry, materials etc.

[image: Release the linked positions]